# Using Firebase A/B testing with Adobe Analytics

Tags: firebase, adobe-analytics, firebase-ab-testing

For my personal mobile app, I have adobe analytics in place for sometime. Now, I am planning to integrate a/b testing in it. I see Firebase A/B testing as an option which is also available for free.

But as I understand that A/B testing works in close collaboration with Analytics data which helps in defining the targeting sets.

So is it a good idea to use Firebase A/B testing with Adobe Analytics in place ?

Comment: Whether it is a good idea would be recommending a technology, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. But I don't know of any reason why Firebase's Analytics and Adobe's Analytics can't be used together in the same app. Either way: if you want to use Firebase's A/B Testing, you will have to use its Analytics in your app too. There is no way to feed analytics data from other vendors into Firebase A/B Testing.

Comment: have you found if that's possible?